# NSIS: find a registry key with wildcards

Tags: nsis

The background for my issue is that I'm trying to move away from a Windows Installer system to NSIS. 
During Installation Users are presented with a list of installed versions of my software and this should include the previous installs made with the Windows Installer system (one can then decide to install in parallel or replace a version).

Now the registry keys for the Windows Installer based installations are in the shape

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MySoftware12.18.12345
```

especially the last part `18.12345` depends on which previous version of my software was installed. 
So I'm trying to find all keys starting with `MySoftware12.`
Is this possible or am I approaching this wrong?

cheers
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumRegKey` can be used to enumerate keys:

```
StrCpy $0 0 ; Registry key index
enumunkey:
    EnumRegKey $1 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" $0
    IntOp $0 $0 + 1
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    StrCpy $2 $1 10 ; 10 is length of "MySoftware"
    StrCmp $2 "MySoftware" 0 enumunkey
    MessageBox MB_OK "Found:$1"
    Goto enumunkey
done:
```

If you also have a 64-bit version that you want to detect then you must also use another loop after calling `SetRegView 64` (And remember to restore it after the loop).